# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - s for array of C-Strings

Tags: c++

I have the following two 2D Arrays of C-Strings. I am trying to copy the first one onto the second using strcpy() function. However, I keep getting the runtime error.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    char word1[3][3] = { "Hello", "Bonjour", "Ni Hao" };
    char word2[3][3] = { "Steve", "Pei", "Frank" };

    char temp[] = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        strcpy(temp, word1[i]);
        strcpy(word1[i], word2[i]);
        strcpy(word2[i], temp);
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << word2[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that a) you would get better help if you provided the actual runtime error, and b) you should provide enough space for each of the strings. There is not A SINGLE string that fits in a 3 character array, if you consider the terminating zero.

Comment: Also, the string `temp` is even shorter than the `word`s and cannot hold anything. Why don't you first try something easier, like using a C++ `std::string` and leave this hard stuff for later?

Comment: You are using two **1D** arrays of "C-strings", BTW. Is your goal to add a "column" (or a row) to an actual 2D array or to overwrite the first array?

Answer (score 0):

In your code i find several mistake.

- your char array `word1`,`word2`,`temp` isn't initialize properly.you need to increase `size` of `array`.
- in loop you use 3.it will break your output if your word's length become grater than 4.

So here i give you little solution.But its better use `user input` as a size of `array` so that any input can match properly.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    char word1[10][10] = { "Hello", "Bonjour", "Ni Hao" };//increase array size to fit word
    char word2[10][10] = { "Steve", "Pei", "Frank" };//same here

    char temp[10] = "";//same here

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        strcpy(temp, word1[i]);
        strcpy(word1[i], word2[i]);
        strcpy(word2[i], temp);
    }


    for (int i = 0; i <10; i++) {
        cout << word2[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```